# Roots Calculation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How does one calculate the roots: $$ \sqrt {57-40\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt {57+40\sqrt{2}}$$  manually?

Also, how can one determine which of the pair is bigger: 
$ \sqrt {3} +\sqrt {5} $  vs.  $ \sqrt {2} +\sqrt {6} $

also, by hand?

Comment: Two completly different questions should be asked separately.

Comment: Maple produces $$ evalf(sqrt(3)+sqrt(5)) $$ $$3.968118785 $$ and $$  evalf(sqrt(2)+sqrt(6))$$ $$3.863703305  .$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^2+2ab+b^2 = (a+b)^2$, $a+2 \sqrt{ab} +b=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2$

Therefore because $57=32+25,　 40\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt{800}=2\sqrt{32×25}$, the expression can be written $(4\sqrt{2}-5) -(4\sqrt{2}+5)$.

So answer is **-10**.

---

$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2=8+2\sqrt{15} > (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})^2=8+2\sqrt{12}$

So, $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5} > \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$

Comment: Awesome man , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

- $\sqrt{57-40\sqrt{2}} \cdot \sqrt{57+40\sqrt{2}}=7$

Answer (score 0):

The square root function increases faster for smaller values, so if $x < y$ then the difference between $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x - 1}$ will be greater than the difference between $\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{y + 1}$. Hence $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 > \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6$.